# change a text with SED command

Tags: php, nginx, centos

i want to change this text :

```
session.save_handler = files
```

to:

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"
```

how to change this text with SED command ?

thank you before

best regards,

maszd

Comment: do you want replace the content of `php.ini`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing whether my command is working fine or not just hit this. You can even test my 1st command online over this [**Execute bash command online**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php)

```
echo "session.save_handler =files" | sed 's/session\.save_handler\s*=\s*files/session.save_handler = memcache\nsession.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"/'
```

In case you have this text in your file lets say `test.txt` just do:

**Actual command:**

```
sed 's/session\.save_handler\s*=\s*files/session.save_handler = memcache\nsession.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"/' test.txt
```

Comment: iam try to this command based above but not working :
sed 's/session\.save_handler\ =\ files/session.save_handler = memcache\nsession.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"/' /etc/php.ini

Comment: i have updated my command can you please check again or share your `php.ini`

Comment: @maszd Working fine for me. i have checked it with my php.ini Can you please check and revert

Comment: thank you very much! iam add `-i` and is working perfect
and here is : `sed -i 's/session\.save_handler\s*=\s*files/session.save_handler = memcached\nsession.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"/' /etc/php.ini` thank for your help :)